# Implementation of different indexers within C# class

Tags: c#, .net, oop, collections, interface

I'd like to add different indexer implementations in my class  :

**SpecificCollection**

```
 public class SpecificCollection<T> : ISpecificCollection <T>
    {
        public int this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

       public object  this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

       public string  this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public event void OnAddElement;

        public event void OnRemoveElement;

        public void AddNewElement(T element)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void DeleteElement(int index)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
```

**StudentSpecificCollection**

```
 public class StudentSpecificCollection : SpecificCollection<Student>
    {

       private string[] arrName;
       private int[] arrAge;
       private object[] arrStudent ;

       public int ISpecificCollectionIndexers<Student>.this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return arrAge[index];
            }
            set
            {
                arrAge[index] = value;
            }
        }

        object ISpecificCollectionIndexers<Student>.this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return arrStudent[index];
            }
            set
            {
                arrStudent[index] = value;
            }
        }

        string ISpecificCollectionIndexers<Student>.this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return arrName[index];
            }
            set
            {
                arrName[index] = value;
            }
        }

        public event void OnAddElement;

        public event void OnRemoveElement;

        public void AddNewElement(Student element)
        {
            object objStudent = arrStudent.Where(x => x != null).LastOrDefault();
            int index = (objStudent == null) ? 0 : Array.IndexOf(arrStudent, objStudent);
            arrName[index] = element.Name ;
            arrAge[index] = element.Age;
            arrStudent[index] = element;
        }

        public void DeleteElement(int index)
        {
            if (index > Count - 1) return;
            arrName[index] = null;
            arrAge[index] = -1;
            arrStudent[index] = null;
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return arrName.Where(x=>x !=null).Count();
            }
            set
            { 
            }
        }
        public StudentSpecificCollection()
        {
            arrName = new string[100];
            arrAge = new int[100];
            arrStudent = new object[100];
        }

    }
```

So I need to know :

1. How can I use the different indexer implementation?
2. What are the best practises to implement differents kinds of indexation in this class?
3. In which cases customizing indexation were better than using the different C# collections?

Comment: You can't create overloads of methods which differ only on return type.

Comment: @Spo1ler Thanks, I'm not asking about the reason of the error it is clear  , but I need a suggestion to implement different kind of indexers

Comment: You can have only one indexer return the object you your class, the properties like name and age could be accessed through that object.

Comment: @LamloumiAfif You can if you implement interfaces

Comment: simply write a generic method to get the items instead... or more methods with a different Name(or signature)

Comment: You can't do an indexer like this. It would most probably require a generic method.

Comment: Your code doesn't makes sense. Why don't you store the `Student` object itself in a collection?

Comment: @CodeCaster : see my edit , I'm asking how can I use multiple indexers?in which case? I didn't understand why this downvotes!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using explicit implementation of interfaces, you can do something like:

```
public interface IMyClass
{
    object this[int index]
    {
        get; set;
    }
}

public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    public string this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return "";
        }

        set
        {
        }
    }

    object IMyClass.this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return "";
        }

        set
        {
        }
    }
}
```

so implement two different enumerators with the same signature (where signature  = type/number of input parameters). Note that you can have multiple interfaces, each one with an indexer with a different return type, so given x interfaces and one class, you can have x + 1 distinct indexers with the same signature.

Now... If `Student` was a "real" class instead of an `object`, you could do some tricks with implicit casts (you can't do implicit casts with/against the `object` class):

```
public class StudentSpecificCollection
{
    private string[] arrName;
    private int[] arrAge;
    private object[] arrStudent;

    public MyObject this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return new MyObject(this, index);
        }

        set
        {
            if (value.Type.HasFlag(MyObject.MyObjectType.Name))
            {
                arrName[index] = value;
            }

            if (value.Type.HasFlag(MyObject.MyObjectType.Age))
            {
                arrAge[index] = value;
            }

            if (value.Type.HasFlag(MyObject.MyObjectType.Student))
            {
                arrStudent[index] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyObject
    {
        [Flags]
        public enum MyObjectType
        {
            Name = 1,
            Age = 2,
            Student = 4
        }

        public readonly MyObjectType Type;
        public readonly string Name;
        public readonly int Age;
        public readonly object Student;

        protected MyObject(string name)
        {
            Type = MyObjectType.Name;
            Name = name;
        }

        protected MyObject(int age)
        {
            Type = MyObjectType.Age;
            Age = age;
        }

        protected MyObject(object student)
        {
            Type = MyObjectType.Student;
            Student = student;
        }

        public MyObject(StudentSpecificCollection obj, int ix)
        {
            Name = obj.arrName[ix];
            Age = obj.arrAge[ix];
            Student = obj.arrStudent[ix];
        }

        public static implicit operator string(MyObject obj)
        {
            if (!obj.Type.HasFlag(MyObjectType.Name))
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }

            return obj.Name;
        }

        public static implicit operator int(MyObject obj)
        {
            if (!obj.Type.HasFlag(MyObjectType.Age))
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }

            return obj.Age;
        }

        //public static implicit operator object(MyObject obj)
        //{
        //    if (!obj.Type.HasFlag(MyObjectType.Student))
        //    {
        //        throw new Exception();
        //    }

        //    return obj.Student;
        //}

        public static implicit operator MyObject(string name)
        {
            return new MyObject(name);
        }

        public static implicit operator MyObject(int age)
        {
            return new MyObject(age);
        }

        //public static implicit operator MyObject(object student)
        //{
        //    return new MyObject(student);
        //}
    }
}
```

(the indexer returns a `MyObject` class that then can be implicitly casted to `int`/`string`)

then use as

```
var obj = new StudentSpecificCollection();
// Load some students here
obj[0] = "Foo";
obj[0] = 25;
string name = obj[0];
int age = obj[0];
```

Note that I **don't** think this is a good idea. But **you** asked for it.

Comment: This works. _But_ you'll have to access the class through the interface (`((IMyClass)instance)[0]`) which is cumbersome. It just doesn't look like OP should use indexers for this.

Comment: @xanatos: thanks,  @CodeCaster you're right , I need to make it like `instance[0]` without casting to an interface

Comment: Great way to make compiler fool :)

Comment: @LamloumiAfif I don't know if you noticed the second example... I **don't** think it is a good idea, but it could be useful for other things.

Answer (score 3):

As [noted by Spoi1ler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28984833/implementation-of-different-indexers-within-c-sharp-class#comment46218368_28984833), the return type is not part of the method signature. So you can't do it like shown in your code.

You can provide multiple indexers using an explicit interface as demonstrated in [Xanatos' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28984987/266143).

The code doesn't make any sense though. Just use one indexer and store and return the student object, so you can do `string name =  lstStudent[0].Name;`.

Comment: I'm not asking about the reason of the error it is clear , I need a suggestion to implement different kind of indexers