# Reason of customizing indexer implementation

Tags: c#, .net, oop, indexing, interface

A C# application may contain `indexer` declaration. Based in this concept, I try to find advantages to customzing the **Indexation Strategy** by re-implementing a class's indexers instead of use it as a type in a collection (Like List, Enumerable...)

I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28984833/implementation-of-different-indexers-within-c-sharp-class) for this customization manner, thanks to [xanatos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/613130/xanatos) who gives me a good answer.

But I'm still not understanding

1. what are the advantages of the re-implemention of indexers?
2. In which cases, it is necessary to re-implement it?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking. If you want to change the behavior of an indexer, that's when it'd be necessary to re-implement one. For example, you may want something like a `CaseInsensitiveDictionary<T> : Dictionary<string, T>`

Comment: @Jacob Sorry but I can't understand your example , can u plz elaborate it more as an answer in which you a short list in cases when it'd be necessary to re-implement an indexer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185071/real-world-use-cases-for-c-sharp-indexers has good examples of custom indexers.